# Free JQGrid - save-button in inlineNav not working when adding a second row

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

we've several Free JQGrids and a problem with adding new rows.
Click on the icon in inlineNav (ADD) a new row will be shown up, clicking the SAVE-Icon the first time works fine. But when adding a second row the Save-buttton in inlineNav will not work. Enter-key in the row works. After reload the whole grid, it will work only once again.

Following is the code of the grid

some defaults:

```
jQuery.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    autowidth: true, pager:true, pgbuttons:false, pginput:false,  
    pgtext:false, datatype: "json", mtype: "POST",    
    rownumbers:true,  rowNum:9999,      
    postData: {"savestate_encrypted" : function() {return $("input[name='savestate_encrypted']").val();}},

    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
           var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
           if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
               $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
           }
           $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
       },
});
```

The grid itself:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:"....",
        jsonReader: {root: "resourceList"},
        height: 500,
        cmTemplate: { editable: true},
        inlineEditing: {keys: true},
        editurl: "....",
        colModel:[ //Define Table Columns
                {name: "name", label:"Name", key:true, hidden:false},
                {name: "activeJobs",  label:"aktive Jobs", width:250}
        ],
    }).jqGrid("navGrid",   {refresh:true, edit:false, del:true, search:false, add:false}) 
      .jqGrid("inlineNav", {save:true, edit:true, add:true})                             
</script>
```

I've figured out that the line 15300 (sorry don't know how to find the branch version - 30.Jan 2017) in the grid source will set the "var ind" to false, when clicking on the button, pressing enter-key works perfect

```
    var tmp = {}, tmp2 = {}, postData = {}, editable, k, fr, resp, cv, savedRow, ind = $self.jqGrid("getInd", rowid, true), $tr = $(ind),
        opers = p.prmNames, errcap = getRes("errors.errcap"), bClose = getRes("edit.bClose"), isRemoteSave, isError,
        displayErrorMessage = function (text, relativeElem)....
```

As a fast solution I wanted to subsribe on an event and reload the whole grid. But subscribe() seems to be gone (we are switching from the old struts-tag grid to javascript. I think bind is the correct way now, but which event?

ADDITION---------------------------

I've created a working code which will show a similiar problem without Ajax and Json. When clicking ADD, enter the values and then selecting SAVE in the inlineNav Bar everything is OK, but pressing ADD again, enter values and then select SAVE, the edit-mode will stay open. If you use the Enter-Key instead the SAVE-btn it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
</head>



<script type="text/javascript">
/* DEFAULTS */
jQuery.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    autowidth: true,    // nutzt die ganze verfügbare Breite
    pager:true,         // Fusszeile -
    pgbuttons:false,    // - ohne Seitenkontrollbuttons
    pginput:false,      // - ohne Eingabefeld
    pgtext:false,       // - ohne Text
    rownumbers:true,    // immer Zeilennummern
    rowNum:9999,        // bis zu 9999 Zeilen

    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
           var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
           if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
               $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
           }
           $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
       },
});



// For JSON Response
/* jQuery.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit,{
    restoreAfterError:false,
    errorfunc: function( response ) 
    { 
        var resp = response;
        alert("error7"); 
        return false; 
    },
   successfunc: function( response ) 
   {
        var resp = response;
        var hasNoError = true;
//      var hasNoError = (resp.responseJSON.actionErrors.length == 0); 
        return hasNoError;
    }
});
 */

function dataset() {
    "use strict";
    var mydata2 = [
            { id: "10",  name: "test"  , value: "5"},
            { id: "20",  name: "test20", value: "5"},
            { id: "30",  name: "test30", value: "5"},
            { id: "40",  name: "test40", value: "5"},
            { id: "50",  name: "test50", value: "5"},
        ];
   return mydata2;
};
</script>



<body>
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
                data: dataset(),
                colModel: [
                    { name: "id", label:"ID"},
                    { name: "name", label:"NAME", align: "center" },
                    { name: "value", label:"VALUE", align: "center" }
                ],
                cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            }).jqGrid("navGrid",   {refresh:true, edit:false, del:true, search:false, add:false}) 
              .jqGrid("inlineNav", {save:true, edit:true, add:true})                             
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Gruß nach Hannover Andreas! Please, post the exact code, which I can use to reproduce the problem if you find an error in free jqGrid. Setting of `var ind = false;` could be not a solution because `ind` should be initialized to the DOM element of editing `<tr>`. I could not repoduce any problem with adding of multiple rows with respect of `inlineNav`. If some bug do exist, at least under some conditions, then it would be good to fix it.

Comment: Danke -Gruss zurück :-) 
I will modify one of the Free JQGrid samples and try to reproduce the error. One idea: we use JQuery 3.3.1 - all samples have 2.x or 1.x versions, but wait until tomorrow - I've to fix a production bug :-(

Comment: free jqGrid supports jQuery 3.3.1 of case. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/customSortIcons-fa4_4.13.6.htm) for example. It uses `inlineNav` and `formatter: "actions"` for inline editing and form editing via `navGrid`. It uses version 4.13.6. Can you reproduce any problem on the demo?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've added a small working sample above - it shows a similiar problem...

Comment: I still can't reproduce any problem. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/saveProblem.html) uses your code with free jqGrid 4.13.6 and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/saveProblem1.html) uses the latest code of free jqGrid from GitHub. I can insert multiple rows and save the data without any problems. I can verify that the data from `id` column will be used additionally as rowid. Could you describe the exact test case to reproduce the problem including web browser, which you use in your tests? I tried both demos in Chrome and IE11 and could not see any problem.

Comment: It's strange- I've included your 'imports' (js and css) and it works local. Seems that there is something wrong with our js-library. These are the headers:

 jQuery v3.1.1 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license 
 jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2017-01-19
 jqGrid 4.13.7-pre - free jqGrid: https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid

I will now get the js from your location and put them in our lib and will test the Ajax-version.

Comment: "4.13.7-pre" is preliminary version of jqGrid. I post every small changes after I did it. It could be that the version 2017-01-19 had some problems fixed at the next day. You should use either the latest released version 4.13.6 or really the latest (it could be unstable and it could be changed every day) version from GitHub. For example, there are exist now the version 2017-02-01, which I tested in the second demo. You should use the latest released version (4.13.6) in production. The current code (2017-02-01) seems be stable too and I plan to publish it as 4.14.0 very soon (at the next days).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem then you want to reload the grid after saving. You can use `jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow` event for the purpose:

```
jQuery("#grid").on("jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
    }, 0);
});
```